# Bound on derivative of $e^{\frac{-\delta^2}{\delta^2-\left( \delta-x \right)^2}+1}$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Define 
$$f(x):=e^{\frac{-\delta^2}{\delta^2-\left( \delta-x \right)^2}+1}$$ for $x\in (0,\delta) $ where $0.5 > \delta>0$.

is it possible  to get a bound on the $L^\infty$ norm of $f'$ on the domain $(0,\delta)$.

I tried writing $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ and $f'(x) = g'(x)e^{g(x)}$, but it seems hard this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)=0=\lim_{x\to\delta} f'(x)$$
Therefore,
$$
\tilde{f}(x)=\begin{cases} f'(x) & x\in(0,\delta)\\0 & x=0~or~x=\delta\end{cases}
$$
is continuous on $[0,\delta]$. Further $[0,\delta]$ is compact which implies that $\tilde f$ is bounded on $[0,\delta]$. Therefore $f'=\tilde f\mid_{(0,\delta)}$ is bounded on $(0,\delta)$.

Comment: But why is the limit of the derivative zero?

Comment: For $x\to 0$ the exponential term dominates towards $0$ while for $x\to\delta$ you have $e^{g(x)}\to 1$ and $g'(x)\to 0$ hence $f'(x)\to 0$.

Comment: Oh... I tried plotting the derivative in WolframAlpha and it says that it blows up at $x \to 0$..

Comment: Might you drop the sign? Because $\delta^2-(\delta-x)^2\to 0^+$ for $x\to 0^+$ yields $\frac{-\delta^2}{\delta^2-(\delta-x)^2}\to -\infty$ for $x\to 0^+$. We conclude $f(x)\to 0$ for $x\to 0$. And $f$ dominates $g'$ because $f$ is exponential and $g$ blows up just polynomial.

Comment: Thanks you are right. Do you know if it's easy to calculate an explicit $L^\infty$ bound?

Comment: You can compute the maximum of $f'$ on $(0,\delta)$. From $f'(x)=g'(x)f(x)$ you can deduce $f''(x)=(g''(x)+(g'(x))^2)f(x)$. And $f(x)>0$ so, the critical points of $f'$ are given by the equation $g''(x)+(g'(x))^2=0$. If I trust Wolfram Alpha, then you just have to solve a quadratic polynomial to get the critical points of $f'$.